# Latency/bandwidth on WebRTC

Tags: webrtc

I had researched on the bandwidth usage of using webRTC to build applications.

I am aware that WebRTC is used for real time P2P communication.

I am unsure if an external signaling server or a local signaling server will affect the latency/bandwidth of the application? Since the signaling server is only used during initial connection to establish communication between host and peers.

Will there be any difference using external signalling server compare to a local server in terms of the bandwidth used?

Answer (score 2):

Some signalling solutions offer the TURN capabilities, others don't. Both cases can have effect on your latency and bandwidth.

[image: TURN connection, thanks to Sam Dutton]

If TURN is available, your peers may fallback to relay connection. This will inevitably increase latency, and may also limit the bandwidth.

If your signalling infrastructure does not include TURN, these two peers will have infinite latency and zero bandwidth (in other words, they will not be able to engage in real time communication).

You can find beautiful illustrations at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/.

Comment: Actually, signalling server itself doesn't know anything about TURN and STUN. It can't offer TURN because this is not something it should work with. Although, some certain frameworks can integrate TURN/STUN offering to their signaling solutions.

Comment: Signalling does carry the ICE candidates which is indirectly related to STUN/TURN.

Comment: @fycth: I would say that you accept a "narrow" interpretation of signalling. For the sake of this discussion, I consider signalling server (note that I tried to carefully use the term *signalling solution*) to be the infrastructure responsible for establishing the P2P connection.

Comment: @AlexCohn The function of signalling is to allow peers to exchange data before establishing direct connection. TURN/STUN parameters are passed by the web browser to RTCPeerConnection when creating new peer connection. This stage happens even before signalling - first, you create a peer connection object (passing TURN/STUN options to the function), and only then you can go to the signaling stage - calling offer or answer functions. Hence, TURN/STUN is not related to signalling infrastructure. Nevertheless, some certain frameworks can integrate TURN options into signaling - but it's NOT the rule

Comment: are there any software/tools to measure how much bandwidth is use for video broadcasting?

Comment: @MickJack you better ask in some special forum that is not devoted to prorgamming

Answer (score 1):

Signalling server is used for establishing direct connection only. The amount of data that is transferred via signalling server is very low. After the direct connection is established, signalling server is out of the table.

Regarding Alex's comment and TURN/STUN solutions: signalling server is not related to TURN or STUN - this is something related to the certain web site (or particular framework) you're working on. Signalling server itself doesn't know anything about TURN or STUN. The function of signalling is to allow peers to exchange data before establishing direct connection: peers exchange with network and media details, and they do it via signaling server because at that stage they can't establish direct connection yet. TURN/STUN parameters are passed by the web browser to RTCPeerConnection method when creating new peer connection. This stage happens even before signalling: first, you create a peer connection object (passing TURN/STUN options to the function), and only then you can go to the signaling stage - calling createOffer or createAnswer methods. Hence, TURN/STUN is not related to signalling infrastructure. Nevertheless, some certain frameworks can integrate TURN options into signaling - but it's NOT the rule.

So, the short answer on your question: signalling server doesn't affect on latency/bandwidth. Although, some certain WebRTC frameworks/solutions can violate this.